# Error ''int' object is not subscriptable' in Euler's method function

Tags: python

I'm trying to apply  [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) to solve the following differential equations:

dA/dt=-k/2 * Ca * Cc;

dB/dt=-k * Ca * Cc;

dD/dt= k* Ca *Cc

And I wanted to get [[t0, t2,...], [[A0, B0,D0],[A1,B1,D1],...] ]
In which A0, B0, and C0 are the concentrations of each product at time t0 (same with A1, B1, D1, but with t1...)

But I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-58-7025b89a5cfb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/catas/OneDrive/Desktop/ER_trab/simulator2_letshopethisworks.py', wdir='C:/Users/catas/OneDrive/Desktop/ER_trab')

  File "C:\Users\catas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\catas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/catas/OneDrive/Desktop/ER_trab/simulator2_letshopethisworks.py", line 70, in <module>
    print(euler(react,0,C0,60,60))

  File "C:/Users/catas/OneDrive/Desktop/ER_trab/simulator2_letshopethisworks.py", line 60, in euler
    C0[0] += h * f(t0, C0[0]) #calculos das aproximacoes y

  File "C:/Users/catas/OneDrive/Desktop/ER_trab/simulator2_letshopethisworks.py", line 44, in react
    dAdt=-k/2*C0[1:][0]*C0[1:][2] #velocidade de consumo de A

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

```
from math import e
initCa=9
initCb=9
initCc=3
initCd=0


C0=[initCa,initCb,initCd]


    
def react(t,C): #are t and T optional???
    k=k0*e**(-Ea/(R*T))
    

    dAdt=-k/2*C0[1:][0]*C0[1:][2] #velocidade de consumo de A
    dBdt=-k*C0[1:][0]*C0[1:][2]#velocidade de consumo de B
    dDdt=k*C0[1:][0]*C0[1:][2] #velocidade de formacao de D

    return [dAdt,dBdt,dDdt]


def euler(f,t, C, tn, n):
    t0=0
    listat=[t0] #lista t inicial
    listay=[C0] #lista y inicial
    h = (tn - t0) / float(n) #step
     
    for i in range(n): 
        C0[0] += h * f(t0, C0[0]) #y
        C0[1] += h * f(t0, C0[1])
        C0[2] += h * f(t0, C0[2])
        t0 += h #calculo dos tempos
        listat.append(format(t0,".14E")) #times list
        listay[i].append(C0) #aproximations list
   
    return [format(h,".14E"),C0,[listat,listay]] 

print(euler(react,0,C0,60,60))
```

I don't understand how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: how is it being called? It seems ```C``` is an integer, yet you are treating it like a list.'

Comment: I've copied and pasted this code, but nothing happens, you haven't included which function should run

Comment: Did you mean to use `f(t0, C0)` inside `euler`?

Comment: Where it tells you `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`, do you understand what this means? If you do not understand it, what do you need help with about it exactly? Do you understand how it relates to the line of code it complains about? In particular, do you see what it implies about `C`?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
C0[0] += h * f(t0, C0[0])
```

You take a single element of `C0` and pass it to your step function (`react`). Apparently those items are integers.

However, within that function:

```
Ca=C[0]
```

You are apparently expecting to receive the entire `C0` list, so that you can extract `Ca` etc. from it. `C` was passed as an integer, so `C[0]` fails as described in the error message.

You need to think more clearly about your program logic, and about what steps of the process will occur where.

Comment: Hello, I understood what you said! And I tried to fix it but now I got a new error! Can you please take a look ! Thank you btw!